# How to clean data when wiping/reinstalling a compromised server?

Tags: server, security, malware

I have a server that has been compromised, where the logs have been blown out and I have neither the ability nor the time to discover what actual pieces of the system were modified. The server was taken offline, and about 400 gigs of research data from multiple users was pulled onto another offline backup. I've scanned the directories with Clam, but am concerned that there may be remnants of malicious code dropped somewhere in the thousands of files.

The files represent years of data logging, but I have no backups against which I could compare them (This penetration was the first I was told about these servers "under my control", and some serious changes are coming), nor knowledge of what should/shouldn't be contained within. Is there some more thorough method for assuring that the data does not contain dormant pieces of malicious code? I can attempt to prevent scripts from executing from within my backup directories, but I'm assuming at some point one of the users will wonder why some code they wrote 2 years ago isn't working and will wind up undoing any security I add.

**TL;DR**: I've been owned. How do I make sure that the data I am copying over to the fresh server installation will not contain potentially malicious code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newbie answer:

- mount with the **`noexec` option** so executables and libraries can't run at all (scripts can't run either, but they can still be invoked with `bash malicious.sh`).

Or

- setup some kind of safe **chroot environment** so you don't mind blowing the entire "system" when a virus tries to nuke you, à la honeypot.

Option 1 has the obvious drawback you can't run any legit code, option 2 has the obvious drawback one single misbehaving executable can nuke all your legit data.

In addition, a **good permission design** (users, groups, sticky bit, setuid bit, etc.) and a restrictive umask should guarantee that a user is only able to blown up its own files (or in his responsibility), which is better than a complete destruction in case of attack.

You can also use a **filesystem with snapshot support** (I won't advertise ZFS too much, it has good things and bad things, you can give it a try). This won't prevent an escalation privilege attack gaining root and deleting your snapshots, but if it's just destruction of data, you can revert back to a previous state).

Comment: I just realized this does not answer the question "How to clean data", but "how to prevent malicious program from deleting data". Anyway I'll keep it since I think it may help the user (and it is the only answer at the moment).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a **`noexec`** mount looks like it'd be useful if I wind up putting the backups on an additional drive. I'm just worried someone is going to wind up copying over their entire directory when they can't execute a script they previously used.

Comment: This is where permissions come in. When a user copies his old working directory to execute something, it can blow all his files if it's a malicious file, but not the whole team work. You can take a look at [limits.conf](http://ss64.com/bash/limits.conf.html) and [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) to avoid things like [forkbombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forkbomb) which would cause a DoS in the system running it for all users and services.